# Subprocess not finishing but script is run correctly

Tags: python, selenium, subprocess

In order to run several scheduled python scripts and capture errors that may arise, I'm using a controller module that opens a subprocess for each script with the following:

```
def _process_script(nm_script, return_val):
    try:
        env = os.environ
        p = subprocess.Popen(['python', nm_script], stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
           shell=False, env=env, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        p.wait()
        (result, error) = p.communicate()

        if p.returncode != 0:
            cd_exec = -1
            tx_exec = error.decode('utf-8')
        else:
            cd_exec = 1
            tx_exec = None

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        cd_exec = -1
        tx_exec = e.output

    return_val += [cd_exec, tx_exec]


def run_script(script):
    return_val = multiprocessing.Manager().list()

    #20 min timeout for the script
    maxDelay = 1200
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=_process_script, args=(script.nm_script, return_val))
    p.start()
    p.join(maxDelay)

    #Checks if the process is still alive
    if p.is_alive:
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
        cd_exec = -1
        tx_exec = 'Timeout'
    else:
        cd_exec = return_val[0]
        tx_exec = return_val[1]

    return return_val
```

The code above has worked for all the scripts so far. There is however one Selenium datascraping script that seems to hang **after** its execution, and I can't seem to find the problem. This is it:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def main():
    path = r'\\path'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    url = '...'
    browser.get(url)

    #...Several steps that do the necessary scraping and export data to the path

    #I have added the following steps to kill the browser instance:
    browser.get('about:blank')
    browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.quit()
    del browser

    return
```

The process executes successfully. The data is exported as expected and the browser instance that had been opened is closed. However, the main script keeps displaying the message regarding DevTools until the timeout of 20 minutes is reached:

```
DevTools listening on ws://...
```

I have several other selenium data scraping scripts that work in a similar manner to this one, and without any trouble so far.
I'm completely lost on this one, what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I see in the above code the author uses Popen() directly and then calls "p.wait()", where "P" is subprocess.

I use subprocess.run() in my code, but Python library reference documentation says that Popen will wait for the process to complete.  Is "p.wait()" necessary?